# Is it ok to read a mysql table every 100ms?

Tags: mysql, database, polling

I made a node app that reads every 100ms a table in a MySQL database, which get updated from a other app (lua), and compares the result with the last result. If the table has changed the app will perform an action. The reading process needs ~0.05ms and it works all perfect. But now am I asking myself wehter this is an acceptable solution or very unprofessional.

Comment: There's better ways to be notified of a change other then pounding on your database which you are using as an API.

Comment: the best option is to program a REST or anny other API interface on the node app that you will trigger with the lua app when the lua app has a update.

Comment: checkout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215104/calling-an-url-from-a-trigger-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited with only the database, I would use two timestamp columns like `updated_at` and `deleted_at` (with indexes maybe - should ask a DB professional) and store the last read time on the client, and then only query the changes made since. This way it'll be more comfortable when using a table with millions of rows.

And except that, It comes to mind that you can use something like websockets to update the client when an update/insert/delete will occur/had occured.

There's another question about this matter:

[Which is more efficient to send WebSocket updates with a MySQL database change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725491/which-is-more-efficient-to-send-websocket-updates-with-a-mysql-database-change)

**Late Edit**

Your "If the table has changed the app will perform an action." sentence is probably the key here. You can just check for something like this:

```
select count(*) from table 
where updated_at > last_update_time or deleted_at > last_update_time
```

then you can decide for to do that action or not.

Comment: You missed the fact that the update is fired with a lua app.. The node app doesn't fire the update.

Comment: Sure the proplem is that the node app needs to be notified when the lua app has a update that requires some kind off API between them.